# How do you include Android N source code inside Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.2, android-7.0-nougat

How do you include/download the Android N source code when developing inside Android Studio?

The documentation/source code isn't currently available inside the Android SDK Manager.

@Passer by Thanks for announcement, I managed to download like that :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source code for Android N is now available from the SDK.

Comment: Thanks, the update is avaliable now I am downloading it : 24.08.2016 22:23 UTC

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there is no available documentation and SDK sources code to download from SDK Manager, only compiled SDK and samples (see [GitHub](https://developer.android.com/preview/samples.html)). But you can use updated for N [API Reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/classes.html) together with [Android API Differences Report](https://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/24/changes.html?utm_campaign=android_launch_npreview_061516&utm_source=anddev&utm_medium=blog) to figure out the code.

**Update:** Google pushed Android 7.0 to AOSP so you can now download the sources for API 24 from SDK Manager

To use N preview SDK in project, update your **build.gradle** as below:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 'android-N'
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.alvenir.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 'N'
        targetSdkVersion 'N'
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed instructions, I'm already using Android N in Android Studio, I was just asking if it was possible to get the source code without having to go online for he API reference/documentations.

I'd hoped that since the documentation was available online, it could somehow also be downloaded locally.